# Rails 3, nginx and unicorn. Why is Rails looking for the development database if I'm in production?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, unicorn

I just deployed an application using capistrano, nginx and unicorn. I used to use Apache and Passenger but I'm trying something new.

I keep on getting error `ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid (Could not find table 'users')` in my production.log (I already checked, the tables DO exist in MySQL).

I kept on looking for the reason of the error and I found out that it seems that Rails is looking for the development database (sqlite3) instead of the production database (mysql).

I followed RailsCast 335 http://railscasts.com/episodes/335-deploying-to-a-vps but I'm using MySQL instead of Postgres.

My database.yml file is located at /apps/myappname/shared/config, and this is what it contains (**no info for test nor development dbs**)...

```
production:
  adapter: mysql2
  database: dbname
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
  host: localhost
  username: db_user
  password: secret
```

**So why isn't Rails looking at this file for database access?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

what about your `gemfile`?

You must specify which database you are using for development and which one for production:

```
# make sure you place your db gems in a group block
group :development do
  gem 'sqlite3'
end

group :production do
  gem 'mysql'
end
```

Comment: yes, that was it, i had `gem 'sqlite3' outside a group. thanks!